# Implementing iterator with a minPQ

Tags: java, iterator

I am so close to being done with this project but the iterator is really stumping me as it pertains to the `MinPQ` and the A* algorithm. Any guidance or tips on how I can better implement this method:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.MinPQ;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Stack;

/**
 * Solver class is used to solve any puzzle that is in the "8 puzzle format" It
 * implements the A* algorithm which is used in path-finding games and map
 * traversals. It approximates the shortest path from start to finish.
 * 
 * @author amie3
 */
public class Solver {
    private SearchNode search;// create a field to implement the SearchNode
    private int movesToSolve;// field used to find the number of moves it takes to solve our initial puzzle
    private boolean canUSolve; // we will initially set it to false in the Solver method
    private Object solution;

    /**
     * The solver method used the A* algorithm to find a solution to the initial
     * board using the MinPQ data type
     * 
     * Generic min priority queue implementation with a binary heap. Can be used
     * with a comparator instead of the natural order. The MinPQ class represents a
     * priority queue of generic keys. It supports the usual insert and
     * delete-the-minimum operations, along with methods for peeking at the minimum
     * key, testing if the priority queue is empty, and iterating through the keys.
     * This implementation uses a binary heap. The insert and delete-the-minimum
     * operations take logarithmic amortized time. The min, size, and is-empty
     * operations take constant time. Construction takes time proportional to the
     * specified capacity or the number of items used to initialize the data
     * structure.
     * 
     * Now, we describe a solution to the problem that illustrates a general
     * artificial intelligence methodology known as the A* search algorithm. We
     * define a search node of the game to be a board, the number of moves made to
     * reach the board, and the predecessor search node. First, insert the initial
     * search node (the initial board, 0 moves, and a null predecessor search node)
     * into a priority queue. Then, delete from the priority queue the search node
     * with the minimum priority, and insert onto the priority queue all neighboring
     * search nodes (those that can be reached in one move from the dequeued search
     * node). Repeat this procedure until the search node dequeued corresponds to a
     * goal board. The success of this approach hinges on the choice of priority
     * function for a search node. We consider two priority functions:
     * 
     * @param initial
     */

    public Solver(Board initial) {
        // corner exception, throw illegal argument if the initial board cannot be
        // solved
        if (initial == null) {
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("sorry, initial board is not solvable :(");
        }
        canUSolve = false; // Initialize with false
        movesToSolve = 0; // initialize with 0
        MinPQ<SearchNode> mini = new MinPQ<SearchNode>(); // create a new instance of the MinPQ class
        // First, insert the initial search node (the initial board, 0 moves, and a null
        // previous search node) into a priority queue.
        mini.insert(new SearchNode(initial, movesToSolve, null));

        // if the board is not solved, go through the instructions within the while loop
        while (!canUSolve) {
            SearchNode lastNode = mini.delMin();// delete from the priority queue the search node with the minimum priority
            if (lastNode.board.isGoal()) {// if this is the goal board
                movesToSolve = -1;
                canUSolve = false;

            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Moves method solves the minimum number of moves to solve the initial puzzle
     * @return the number of moves it takes to solve
     */
    public int moves() {
        return movesToSolve;
    }

    /*
     * create a search node for the game to be a board, the number of moves made to
     * reach the board and the predecessor search node
     */
    private class SearchNode implements Comparable<SearchNode> {
        private SearchNode previous; 
        private Board board;
        private int priority; // create an instance of board
        public Board board;
        // constructor for the search node to implement First, insert the initial search
        // node
        // (the initial board, 0 moves, and a null previous search node) into a priority
        // queue.
        public SearchNode(Board initial, int movesToSolve, Object object) {

                this.board = board;
                this.priority = board.manhattan() + movesToSolve;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(SearchNode other) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return this.priority - other.priority;
        }

    }
    /**
     * This methods allows you to able to get an instance of an Iterator, which is
     * the needed instance used by the "foreach" loop in our main method
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Iterable<Board> solution() {
         return null; 
    }   
}
```